# FAILURE: Build failed with an exception,Android resource compilation failed

Tags: android

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show"
        android:background="@drawable/back"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

When I run this code,I show this Error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

  > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
  >   Android resource compilation failed

Answer (score 0):

try this, in Android Studio

```
File > Invalidate Caches/Restart...
```

See ya.

Comment: Do you have more log? I need to see it.

Comment: E/UsbPortManager: connectToProxy: usb hal service not found. Did the service fail to start?
    java.util.NoSuchElementException

Comment: E/PowerManagerService: Failed to read last_reboot_reason file
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/misc/reboot/last_reboot_reason (No such file or directory)

Answer (score 0):

Merging an application explains itself. Your compiler is unable to merge because some resources are missing. In your case, I see the text on your button is hash coded meaning there is no string resource stored for it. Just alt + Enter at the text to generate the resource

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/show" <!--THE STRING RESOURCE.-->
    android:background="@drawable/back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```